Beamer : Only show subset of overlays with handout mode
In my presentation I would like to show only a subset of overlays when using handout mode (useful to get a student version of my slideshow without giving too much details).
I can achieve what I want (display only items 1 and 2) with the following:
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Frame 1}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> item 1
  \item<2-> item 2 
  \item<3-|handout:0> item 3 % this does not appear in handout mode
  \item<4-|handout:0> item 4 % this does not appear in handout mode
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

but this is not convenient when the frame is more complex. I would like to be able to specify the desired overlays by the global frame options, something like:
\begin{frame}<handout:1-2>
 \frametitle{Frame 2}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> item 1
  \item<2-> item 2 
  \item<3-> item 3 % this should not appear in handout mode
  \item<4-> item 4 % this should not appear in handout mode
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Any ideas?

I'm not sure this is possible. The frame option is doing something different. (I use this a lot because it does precisely what I want, which is not what you're looking for :(.) <4-> just means: show on slide 4 and later in presentation mode where you don't have to specify the mode because presentation is default. If you want the spec to apply to some other mode, you have to override that e.g. <4-| handout:4> would work i.e. it wouldn't show up in the handout version.

@Tobard Unrelated to your question, but you neither need \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} nor \usetheme{default}.  The former is used by default for a couple of years now and the later, well, as the name says, is the default theme.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I edited my message to remove these useless commands. Thanks.

You can pick one or more specific overlays for the handout like this:
\documentclass[
  handout
]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<handout:2>
 \frametitle{Frame 2}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item<all:1-> item 1
  \item<all:2-> item 2 
  \item<all:3-> item 3 % this should not appear in handout mode
  \item<all:4-> item 4 % this should not appear in handout mode
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<handout:2>
 \frametitle{Frame 2}
 \begin{itemize}[<all:+->]
  \item item 1
  \item item 2 
  \item item 3 % this should not appear in handout mode
  \item item 4 % this should not appear in handout mode
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Another approach: you could redefine how items are parsed
\documentclass[
  handout
]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@parseitem<#1>{%
  \gdef\beamer@closeitem{%
    %% Handle empty item as LaTeX would do
    \if@inlabel\indent\par\fi
    \end{actionenv}%
    %% Local change inside actionenv should survive, and should be
    %% always false
    \@noparitemfalse}%
  \begin{actionenv}<all:#1>\beamer@callorigitem}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<handout:2>
 \frametitle{Frame 2}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> item 1
  \item<2-> item 2 
  \item<3-> item 3
  \item<4-> item 4 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


I hoped you'd answer this one ;).

@cfr ... of course I wouldn't want to disappoint you :)

You could also say \begin{frame}<1-| handout:1-2>[<all:+->] since the OP asked specifically about global options for the frame. I'd forgotten about all and couldn't think what to put.

@cfr yes, or one could change the default overlay specifications. Many possibilities...

Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. This solution works but it needs to add all to every overlay command. Is there a more generic way? What do you mean by "change the default overlay specifications"?

@Tobard With default overlay specification, I meant \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<all:+->} instead of manually animating your list

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz : I see. So no way to impose all prefix to all overlay specs by default?

@Tobard I added another approach, not promises that this won't break anything else
